# Perform action on all fields of structure

Tags: matlab, struct

I wonder if it's possible to perform an action on *all* fields of a structure at once?

My scenario:

I have data from an eye tracker device. It is stored in a struct `Data`, and has the following fields:

```
Data.positionX
Data.positionY
Data.velocity
Data.acceleration
```

Each field contains a vector of integers. Suppose I want to delete sample number 10 from my data stream. I would have to do the following:

```
Data.positionX(10) = [];
Data.positionY(10) = [];
Data.velocity(10) = [];
Data.acceleration(10) = [];
```

How would I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/02/27/dynamic-field-name-usage/).

```
fields = fieldnames(Data);
for i=1:length(fields)
   field  = fields{i};
   Data.(field)(10) = [];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is simple enough, it may be worth switching to a structure where you index the data directly instead of its contents

```
Data(10).positionX
Data(10).positionY
...
```

then it would have been as simple as

`Data(10)=[]`

Or alternately, if you have a bunch of vectors you want to store together, you may be better off storing them in a matrix:

```
M = [positionX positionY] %And so on, possibly transposed
```

Then it would have been as simple as:

```
M(10,:)=[];
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable way of doing things. However, wouldn't this be very memory-intensive? Since every sample would have a list of field names associated with it..? My Structure `Data` usually contains around 500000 samples.

Comment: Have not tested it but would expect the memory requirements to be comparable. Of course a matrix will probably use least memory as it is the most simple.